# slack にて、heroku 上で動作している hubot から応答がない

Tags: heroku

下記の記事を参考に bot を作成しました。
http://memo.sanographix.net/post/88371442780
hubot と heroku を用いて slackの発言に対して反応するようにしたいと思っております。
デプロイ完了後、channelに招待していざ slack から

```
@maki ping
```

と入力しても反応がありません。
[image: botアカウント]
botのアカウントも上記画像のようにオンラインになっていない状態です。
どのようにデバッグしていけばいいか、ご回答いただけると幸いです。

Comment: `heroku logs`でエラーを吐いてないか確かめてみてください:)

Comment: `heroku logs` ではエラーはでておりませんでした！
redis cloudを使っておりますが、そちらもエラーは吐かれておりませんでした...

Comment: hubot-slack v3からbotもchannelに招待しないと反応しなくなりましたが、 /invite はしてありますか?

Comment: channel に招待しておりますが、反応がない状態です...